# Push notification on iMessage Extension App

Tags: ios10, imessage

I'm creating an iMessage Sticker Extension App on iOS 10. I'd like to push remote notification when the system have a new sticker.
Can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

If your extension is embedded into an iOS app, you could use the iOS app as the receiver of the push notification. That will work for sure.

Comment: I'm new with iMessage Application on iOS.

I'm researching to understand Push Notification and how to write code to communicate between host app and extension. It's would be great if you can share some code or detail guide.

Thank you!